# why i need to add white-space in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete function in one of my project.
In auto complete when I type `a` it is showing some suggestion like `action`, `apple`,`asp`.

If I select any suggestion from them and click on send then it send only `a` in chat.
if I added any white-space or any character before sending, then it sends full string which I selected from the suggestion.
I tried to search for this problem my I did not find any solution so I am posting it here I am very new to jQuery.

this is my code

```
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  var availableTags = [
   "Remote ping one",
   "Remote ping two",
   "Remote ping three",
   "Remote ping four",
   "Server reporting",
   "Server Dashboard",
   "Server Detail",
   "Network Dashoboard",
   "Netwokr reporting"

  ];
  $( ".wc-shellinput" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
  });
} );
</script>
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the relevant code related to the question, ie autocomplete setup, code that gets and then sends the value

Comment: We need more information, depending on your autocomplete configuration.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  i updated my question

Comment: that code works, where are you sending it where only one letter gets sent wheres the send function

Comment: You need to show the code where you get the value and send it. Side note you are including the jQuery library twice